# Bug that only happens in unity3d, c# (using Graphs)

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, graph

So, here is the problem:

I have a graph class (and vertex and edge) to set up a graph. However, in C# (in unity3d), whenever I am adding a new vertex to my vertexList, the previous vertexes that were added get rewritten with the new one.

Now, I was so confused, I even asked a university student and my computer science teacher, they were stomped, they said it themselves.

Then, I tried to see if I wrote something wrong, so I wrote the whole thing (just the parts that help make the vertexList) in Python. And it worked as it should have in c# too.

Below you can see the C# code (link):

Graph class - https://hastebin.com/usizigepaf.cs

Vertex class - https://hastebin.com/ofiyozodun.cs

Edge class - https://hastebin.com/riwazawaki.cpp (this should say cs for c#, I don't know why it says cpp, it's fine anyway)

And here is the python code:

All - https://hastebin.com/ukokujesal.rb

---

You might find more code in the c# codes, but that is because I want to set up edges too, however, I need to set up vertexes first... that is the main problem here that I want to focus on and need help with.

So, how do I solve the problem? What is going wrong?

---

EDIT:

The problem starts when I add to the vertexList, basically on line 17 of the graph class. That line calls the method which starts at line 45, therefore, the problem can only be, in my opinion, within the method (addVertex(data)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste any code you think should be considered directly into your question, what would happen if the link stops working? In general, you should make it as easy as possible for us to help you - have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to formulate a good question likely to elicit help. You should pay attention to how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Oh, okay, got it, I will do that next time! 

Thank you. 

I now edited and said what I think the problem might be coming from.

Comment: I believe the problem is with your use of `GetComponent<Vertex>()`. I think you only have a single `Vertex` component when, in reality, your design is to add multiple during your scripting? At the moment, `setVertex` always applies to the same `Vertex` component.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Now, I am using the "new" keyword to do it.

So it looks like this:


```Vertex vertex = new Vertex();```

However, I get an error saying that I am not allowed to create MonoBehaviour using the "new" keyword. What should I do instead?

Comment: I think you need to re-consider your approach. You could add a new `Vertex` using `AddComponent`, but it would be odd to have multiple components of the same type. You might prefer to have a `Vertices` component, which stores multiple objects of type `Vertex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem clearly lies in

```
public void addVertex(Transform data)
{
    Debug.Log("data: " + data);
    //Vertex vertex = new Vertex(data);

    Vertex vertex = GetComponent<Vertex>();
    vertex.setVertex(data);
    Debug.Log("vertex: " + vertex);

    vertexList[graphIndex] = vertex;
   // Debug.Log("Type of item at graphIndex " + graphIndex + ": " + vertexList[graphIndex]);
   // Debug.Log("Data within the item at graphIndex " + graphIndex + ": " + vertexList[graphIndex].getVertex());

   graphIndex++;
}
```

where `GetComponent<Vertex>()` always returns the **same** instance of `Vertex` (the first encountered) attached to this GameObject.

As you figured `new` is forbidden for `MonoBehaviour` classes.

---

Actually there is no reason why `Vertex` should be a `MonoBehaviour` at all. Simply make it

```
[System.Serializable] // <- makes this class visible in the Inspector
                      //    including its serialized fields
public class Vertex
{
    ...

    public Vertex(Transform dataP)
    {
        data = dataP;
    }

    ...
}
```

so you can use `new`

```
public class Graph : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializedField] private Vertex[] vertexList;

    ...

    public void addVertex(Transform data)
    {
        Debug.Log("data: " + data);

        var vertex = new Vertex(data);

        Debug.Log("vertex: " + vertex);

        vertexList[graphIndex] = vertex;
       // Debug.Log("Type of item at graphIndex " + graphIndex + ": " + vertexList[graphIndex]);
       // Debug.Log("Data within the item at graphIndex " + graphIndex + ": " + vertexList[graphIndex].getVertex());

        graphIndex++;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

You might also ant to consider to use a `List<Vertex>` instead of the array and index if you are going to add vertices dynamically.

Comment: Well, that works, thank you, but, it makes another bug - I think it's a bug, I will put the screenshot here so you can have a look:

https://imgur.com/a/3bJRXaj

I don't exactly know what native class it's referring to. And the other one I have no clue what it's trying to say. This is the first time I encounter these bugs :\

Comment: well did you try to add the tag `[ExtensionOfNativeClass]`? You add tags same way as `[System.Serializable]` .. simply place it above the class

Comment: ```[ExtensionOfNativeClass]``` does not exist apparently

Comment: Oh I think you somewhere still have a `Vertex` attached to a GameObject which is not allowed anymore since it is no `MonoBehaviour` anymore .. find the GameObject and remove the broken component

Comment: That worked, though I had to remove ```[System.Serializable]``` from the ```Edge class``` since I wanted to make that a not ```MonoBehaviour``` too as I had a similar bug which would have been solved by using the ```new``` keyword.

All done I think. Thank you very much. (Even though when typing here says avoid saying thank you, I have to say thank you, I was really confused like extremely confused).

Comment: @eight8 glad to help and that you could figure it out! I think its okey to say thank you as long it is not the only thing you do ;) They want to avoid long conversations in the comments and sometimes when I see them I also flag them to be removed in the future ^^